# How to add new in-app product which is not yet presented in app?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have an app, which is using in-apps, now I want to add a new in-app, but it's not yet presented anywhere. It will only show at the end of the month, when my customer add new record on the server side. But fortunately I have an Id for a SKProduct and I know the name of it. How I can provide a screenshot of this product to approval team?

P.S: App was designed for this kind of logic, I don't need to update the app every time when new product appear on the server.

Comment: Surely you have a test version of your app running where you are testing your new in app?

Comment: For new In-App you need to update a version of your app, else it won't work live.

Comment: @Paulw11 no, we have only one working backend for dev and prod version, I don't have any info about new SKProduct except i wrote in the main description. I just know it's id and name.

Comment: @iphonic you are not right. If i'm getting in-app ids from backend i can buy also new ones

Comment: @NosovPavel you might be able to buy in sandbox mode are you able to buy in Production (app downloaded from iTunes store)?

Comment: @iphonic sure, i can. But the problem is: i don't any content for buying. For example I need to add 10 items in advance and when they appear on the backend, i wouldn't do anything with the app and products.

Comment: You just mock your back end response in a test version of your app and take a screenshot. The screenshot for Iap review isn't that important anyway